# WPF global variables?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, global

This question is quite tricky to word, so please do ask if my explanation is lacking.

I have an application that has several `datagrids` which contain `editable objects`, for example **containers**, **shipments** and **packages**.

Now each of these objects (**shipment**, **container**, **package** etc.) often require knowledge of the selected item in another `datagrid` (for example, **package** needs to know what **container** is selected in the **containerviewmodel**) usually i would fire an event when `selectedItem` changes and listen for those events on the `viewmodels` that require this information, however recently changes have been made which require `models` to know about selections.

So my question is, would it be "bad practice" or bad code wise to have a single class which contains all the currently selected items from all `viewmodels`, and simply listen to `events` in that single class, which is then used by `viewmodels` and models to find out about selected items? (Using `IoC.get<>` in order to get the instance of the "global" class)

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: that is an awful lot of code and xaml, is there a specific part you need to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, I would say that it was 'bad practice', as you say, to have model data type classes needing to know anything about selected items. I have always believed that the data type classes should just be 'holders of data' and have very little or no functionality... *that* is the job of the view models.

What I might do in your situation is have a parent view model that holds all of the collections *and* properties to bind to the selected items from each collection. That way, you could deal with everything in one location. The child views could bind directly to the parent view model as well if that would help:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Shipments, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Views:ParentView}}}" />
```

Comment: that seems like a good clean solution, i was a little concerned about adding functionality to my data objects, but they handle the endedit functionality, which in my datagrid requires additional data that is not available on that data object (such as the selected container) in order to save (which is handled by another class, which is where i decided to have the selected container bound, and add the information just before saving. Your solution certainly sounds far cleaner in general however, and i may switch my event system into this style.